# Which was the first Star Wars book/comic book/cartoon/tv series/movie not to involve the Skywalkers?

Tags: star-wars, andor

I've been watching *Andor* lately and have been loving it so far, especially the exclusion of any mention of the Skywalkers.

So similarly, which was the first *Star Wars* movie, television show, comic book, or anything else to do this—that is not involving the Skywalkers in their storyline. (It should be noted [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231047/are-there-any-star-wars-stories-that-exclude-the-force?rq=1) asks about the Force as a whole, while I only mean the Skywalker family. All I want is the first official *Star Wars* thing to not contain any mention of the Skywalkers.)

Answers from the Disney era and the legends are acceptable.

Comment: Star Wars #28 (1977) has a Han Solo plot that only contains one mention of Vader, in flashback (and you don't see him, only one of his Star Destroyers in the background)

Comment: If you consider the segments of the Star Wars Holiday Special (1978) as separate works, then some (mostly the musical ones) lack the mention of the Skywalkers.

Comment: @Valorum: what? Vador is a Skywalker? You should warn about spoilers!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This [list](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_novels_by_release_date) provides a chronological order of all expanded universe (legends and cannon) novels that have been published.

[Han Solo at Star's End](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_at_Stars%27_End) published 1st April 1979 is the first work not to include any Skywalkers. It does include both Han and Chewbacca. As noted in Valorum's comment, [there was a 1980 comic book adaptation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_at_Stars%27_End_(comic_strip)).

Comment: Although, that is a book.

Comment: True, but the question title and the body are slightly at odds. I cannot find another earlier non Skywalker comic so I think you may have it on that

Comment: There was a comic strip conversion of this story published in 1980 https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_at_Stars%27_End_(comic_strip)

Comment: I remember getting that book as a teenager, and being confused by “Stars End”, which was also a thing in the Foundation books

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure there will be an earlier comic, but *[The Ewok Adventure](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087225/)* came out in 1984 and does not involve the Skywalkers.

> The Towani family civilian shuttlecraft crashes on the forest moon of Endor. The four Towani's are separated. Jermitt and Catarine, the mother and father are captured by the giant Gorax, and Mace and Cindel, the son and daughter, are missing when they are captured. The next day, the Ewok Deej is looking for his two sons when they find Cindel all alone in the shuttle (Mace and Cindel were looking for the transmitter to send a distress call), when Mace appears with his emergency blaster. Eventually, the four-year old Cindel is able to convince the teenage Mace that the Ewoks are nice. Then, the Ewoks and the Towani's go on an adventure to find the elder Towanis

Comment: The Ewoks and Droids cartoons that came out in 1985 being second place winners for no Skywalkers.

Comment: @lucasbachmann The [2nd Ewoks movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor) was also 1985, though later in the year (November), so probably after the cartoons.